# Unity sprite editor don't import Sprites

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have one really hard problem without any solution , I tried to update Unity on the newest version and the problem still persist. I don't know if i make any wrong setup of Unity Edit or I need to click something more to import sliced sprites.

My problem is when i upload picture in good quality and when i open up Sprite Editor in unity on the same image i try to do Automatic slice to get more objects from same image..
Something like this i put on settings

[image: my settings]

It slices everything correctly because i can press onto diffrent objects and see the borders , i click apply and when i press x if he as i click apply again. When Sprite Editor closes i don't get any sliced sprites into my project folder.

So, My question is How to import automatic sliced sprites from sprite editor to my project ?

Please help me it seems I am really dumb to find solution for this alone.

Thank you for your time on reading my post. I hope there is one expert who can help me with this problem.....

p.s. so i slice it like this I click slice, then i click apply and press X on window and i don't see any sprites in my folder....

[image: description]

Comment: You don't get additional files in the project folder. Every sprite-Asset in Unity has a little triangle left of the icon, just  like a folder. If you click that, you will see all the different spritesin that asset.

Comment: I don't completely understand what your actual goal is ... but the SpriteEditor might not be the tool you are seraching for. `Slice` here means that the Sprite will cale only the borders but keep the center part unscaled when you scale the rect ... doesn't sound like this is what you are actually after ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the sprite type is set to "Multiple" and you set the filtering to Point.

This will allow the sprite to be split and expand in the inspector. You won't get multiple files.

Comment: Already put Sprite -> Multiple..
I tried to put filtering to Point but same issue happens.. I dont know what to do and i really need Auto Slice..I mean it slices image correctly, but it don't import objects or slice pieces...please help me guys with this issue..

Comment: Please post an image of the sprite import settings.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/storage/attachments/84892-aniso-level.png

Thank you i hope you will find solution for me..

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution , Everything worked but i didn't know how to open more images , by clicking into image in my sprites on small arrow -> 
It show me all the sprites sliced correctly.

Thank you everyone for your help.